# how to copy the grid data to object

Tags: linq, casting, grid

I am trying to copy the grid data to one object.

Code :

```
object obj = GrdReport.ItemsSource;    
PrepareDataForStackedChart1(obj);
```

The function is defined as

```
private void PrepareDataForStackedChart1(object categoies)           
{              
    var Salespersons = (from cat in categoies    
                    select cat.Salesperson);    
}
```

I am getting error :

> Cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

Can anyone tell me how I can access the object in a linq query?

Comment: You need to cast categories to its type

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Just happened to learn you are using a third party control ([from your duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340283/how-to-copy-the-itemsource-data-to-any-collecion-type?lq=1)) whose `ItemSource` property takes `System.Object` and not `IEnumerable`. In that case either cast your object (`ItemSource`) back to the original type, or maintain the original collection you used to bind the control somewhere and pass that collection to your `PrepareDataForStackedChart1` method.

Some guess work:

1) **Either**

```
object obj = GrdReport.ItemsSource;    
PrepareDataForStackedChart1((IEnumerable<Category>)obj);

private void PrepareDataForStackedChart1(IEnumerable<Category> categories)           
{              
    var Salespersons = (from cat in categories    
                    select cat.Salesperson);    
}
```

2) **or** when you do

```
GrdReport.ItemsSource = GetCategories();
```

Copy a back up as well like this:

```
categories = GetCategories(); //categories is defined in proper scope.
GrdReport.ItemsSource = categories;
```

And later you do;

```
PrepareDataForStackedChart1(categories);

private void PrepareDataForStackedChart1(IEnumerable<Category> categories)           
{              
    var Salespersons = (from cat in categories    
                    select cat.Salesperson);    
}
```

3) **or may be you will get the collection from `Items` or `Rows` property (perhaps) defined on your GridView**. Good luck..

---

**Pre edit**:

The error is because you cant enumerate a plain object. It has to be enumerable. Why are you passing an object value to your `PrepareDataForStackedChart1` method? Instead can't you pass the `IEnumerable` itself? Try

```
var categories = GrdReport.ItemsSource.OfType<Category>();    
PrepareDataForStackedChart1(categories);

private void PrepareDataForStackedChart1(IEnumerable<Category> categories)           
{              
    var Salespersons = (from cat in categories    
                        select cat.Salesperson);    
}
```

I am assuming you have parent class `Category`

Comment: I am creating reports in silverlight.GrdReport using datagridveiw.In my report i have to had few more column by using check-box. when  i check the check-box...columns are adding to DatagridView. That's  why i am using directly Itemsource value. Insted of using your second option.

Comment: @NeeruBindela Its hard to follow from here. Read your posts from the view of a third person who knows nothing about your post. You wil realise how hard it is to understand your problem.

Comment: In your intellisense, it will list a set of methods, properties, fields, events etc listed on the gridview object. In other words, put a dot after `GrdReport` and you will see it will have some collection of gridview rows. It will be named either `Rows` or `Items`. it will look like `GrdReport.Rows` or `GrdReport.Items` and then you can pass it to your `PrepareDataForStackedChart1` method by casting appropriately. May be like this: `GrdReport.Items.OfType<Category>()`.